# How do I get return value on different color in front end

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have backend code written in python where it returns a number, I want to show the number in different color for certain threshold.

For example if the number is 15 and above it should show in red color

Here is the code:

```
def zulu_extracts(weather_input,datis=None):
    
    # This could be work intensive. Make your own conversion if you can avoid using datetime
    raw_utc = Root_class().date_time(raw_utc='HM')[-4:]
    raw_utc_dt = datetime.strptime(raw_utc,"%H%M")
    
    if datis:
        zulu_item_re = re.findall('[0-9]{4}Z', weather_input)
    else:
        zulu_item_re = re.findall('[0-9]{4}Z', weather_input)
        
    if zulu_item_re:
        zulu_weather = zulu_item_re[0][:-1]
        zulu_weather_dt = datetime.strptime(zulu_weather,"%H%M")
        diff = raw_utc_dt - zulu_weather_dt
        diff = int(diff.seconds/60)
        return diff
    else:
        zulu_weather = 'N/A'
        return zulu_weather
```

The front end is based on html,css and JS

I already searched on google and tried chat GPT but nothing seems to work

Comment: I don't think *how* you generate this number is particularly relevant. But how does this number get added to the front end? In the html? Via Javascript? What did you try and how did it fail to meet your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to generate HTML with `zulu_extracts` then change the lines

```
diff = int(diff.seconds/60)
return diff
```

to

```
diff = int(diff.seconds/60)
if diff >= 15:
    return '<span style="color: red">{}</span>'.format(diff)
return diff
```

But it would be much better to do this kind of styling in the place where the rest of your HTML is generated.